# Are there any public/free nodes to connect a Dapp front end?

Tags: dapps, nodes

I have a small Dapp written in Meteor (client only) that reads some contract and account info from the blockchain.  I can deploy my front-end code for free on meteor.com (or a variety of other places), but I still need a node to connect to.

Do I need to host my own node?  If so, any recommendations? I'm using Digital Ocean $5 VPS now, and it's really, really slow.

If not, are there free/public options?

Answer (score 10):

You may use Infura as a ***"read only / signed transactions only"***  node.

The use of the API is free: https://infura.io

Your may recommend your users to use [Metamask](http://metamask.io) Browser extension to be able to sign transactions in your App.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @digitaldonkey What makes it a read-only node? Methods like `eth_sendRawTransaction` enables us to write new data as well, right?

Comment: @jeff You are right. But you will need a transaction-signer (like Metamask.io) in order sign transactions on the frontend side in order to "write" into the blockchain.
Infura has no eth_coinbase so you can't use it to "write" unsigned data.

Comment: @digitaldonkey Good point. Maybe we should call it a signed-only node? :)

Comment: Noob question from someone struggling to get all this, but if I am developing a native app, the private key can be part of the native app and the signature generated by the app right? I mean, beyond that I wouldn't need something like metamask in that case, correct?

Comment: @Sentinel Yes some apps do manage the key for you.

Comment: Using infura solved my problem. They provide an Ethereum node which can be accessed from the public internet using the standard Ethereum RPC.

Answer (score 9):

If you are deploying an app at scale, you probably don't want a mere node.  **You want a full and performant [web API](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/555/are-there-any-blockchain-transaction-apis-for-the-ethereum-network)**.  There are several available:  I've personally used [etherscan.io](http://etherscan.io/) and been reasonably happy with it.

If it's just a testing project, spinning up your own node isn't too bad.  **But if you're using any of the actual node functionality, such as accounts, then you can't really use someone else's**.  And if you're not...web API all the way.

Comment: etherscan's "proxy" API is incompatible with JSON-RPC, though, so you can't point web3.js at it.

Comment: Right, that's my second bolded point.

Comment: This kind of thing is confusing me about Ethereum - I thought the whole point was decentralization but it seems if you want to develop a distributed app, you still need to go to Azure or something to host a node. I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: @Sentinel you don't **need** to go through Azure or AWS to host a node, you can always spin up your own node on your own metal, its just a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK Mist is meant to provide you access to a node locally (the official Ethereum wallet is a full node), but I don't know if it is functional yet.

An alternative would be e.g. [MetaMask](http://metamask.io) (in alpha).

Comment: Yeah, I have no problem running a node locally, but I can't/won't leave my personal computer running 24/7 to power a Dapp.  I signed up for updates to MetaMask.

Comment: Note MetaMask is a web3js wrapper connecting to Infura.