# Are there any blockchain/transaction APIs for the Ethereum network?

Tags: web3js, explorers, explorer-api

In the Bitcoin world there are a number of APIs such as:

blockchain.info blockr.io blockcypher.com etc.

which allow a web application to access block and transaction data from the blockchain, as well as send transactions.  Are there similar services available for the Ethereum network?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [REST-Like API for Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26155/rest-like-api-for-ethereum)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah there are some, i found

1. https://www.etherchain.org/apidoc
2. https://atmospherejs.com/ethereum
3. http://blockapps.net/apidocs

My understanding is that, we can create a node on our own and access the node with `web3.js` so that we can reduce latency issues.

Answer (score 5):

https://infura.io/ is another one that provides a regular Ethereum JSON-RPC endpoint as well as an IPFS gateway.

Answer (score 2):

[Ethporer](https://ethplorer.io) provides very cool [Ethereum Tokens API](https://github.com/EverexIO/Ethplorer/wiki/Ethplorer-API).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33952)

Comment: This link is to API reference. The question was not about concrete method but in general.

Comment: but you answered the same thing with the same link on too many questions today IMO. Perhaps not spam but looks like...

Answer (score 0):

[Blupee](https://blupee.io) provides an easy way to interact with Ethereum, OmiseGo and ERC20 tokens through a RESTFUL interface.

Today one SDK exists that wraps Blupee, written in Ruby and packaged as a [gem](https://github.com/fogonthedowns/blupee).

Answer (score 0):

[Cindercloud](https://cinder.cloud) also offers an API to interact with ethereum smart contracts or perform various other tasks (like listening for smart contract events). It also has a [js-sdk](https://docs.cinder.cloud).

Answer (score 0):

[Nodesmith](https://nodesmith.io/docs/#/) is a JSON RPC SaaS with blazing speed due to caching. Supports Ethereum Mainnet, Testnets, and sidechains such as AION, POA, xDai.

[BlockScout](https://blockscout.com/eth/mainnet/api_docs) is an opensource Ethereum explorer with JSON and GraphQL APIs. Hosted version supports Ethereum Mainnet, Testnets, Ethereum Classic, RSK, POA, xDai.