# REST-Like API for Ethereum

Tags: external-api, explorer-api

I'm researching REST-Like API services for Ethereum in order to use it on our service. However, there are only a few services I could find. I'd very grateful if you could share the other services.

REST-Like API (I'm looking for these kind of services)

https://etherscan.io/apis

https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/ethereum/#introduction

https://www.etherest.io/

https://github.com/EverexIO/Ethplorer/wiki/ethplorer-api

JSON-RPC wrapper

https://www.myetherapi.com/

https://infura.io/docs/#calling-a-json-rpc-method

Memo

https://svelte-hn.now.sh/item/15019722

Comment: But you can't use this rest api's to build up a service to use ethereum for example for your business or may i wrong?

Comment: @dyoser While it depends how much you want to use the 3rd-party apis, I don't think I can use it on my production service. One reason is I have to handle heavy traffic. Take etherscan for example, they have some limitations. I think I need to build my own block explorer. If you know any good open sources, I'd be grateful if could share. I could not find it so far.

Comment: https://www.etherest.io/ is no longer available.

Answer (score 8):

You haven't mentioned it, but there is always the basic [Ethereum JSON-RPC API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC). It's essentially what Infura offers, but you could run it yourself. It's supported by all the main Ethereum implementations. I reccomend this route, or using something like Infura that meets this API, because then you will be able to easily switch providers and not have to rewrite the code around each API endpoint your use.

Also, a service you didn't list is [Etherchain's API](https://etherchain.org/documentation/api/).

Comment: Etherchain's API still works but documentation is down (can't find it in case URL just changed)

Answer (score 1):

There's a newer one that others haven't mentioned and that's [Amberdata.io](https://Amberdata.io). They have a lot of data and [a lot of API endpoints](https://docs.amberdata.io/reference/reference-getting-started). Definitely worth checking out. They have [JSON-RPC compliant websockets](https://docs.amberdata.io/reference/connection) which should alleviate the issue described by Steve.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

[Cindercloud](https://cinder.cloud/ethereum-contract-api) also has an Ethereum API, mainly aimed at contract calls and balances/token balances. [Arkane Network](https://arkane.network/) has a full data api including all historic data for multiple chains and is easily queryable.

Answer (score 1):

You can also checkout Etherniti REST API Proxy at https://hub.docker.com/r/etherniti/proxy-oss. It seems to be compatible with latests versions of Ethereum and similars, including raw JSON-RPC support and more stuff I didnt try it yet

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [QuikNode.io](https://www.quiknode.io) web3 developer platform. Native JSON-RPC APIs for Ethereum and Bitcoin, plus tools like request analytics, security, webhooks for smart-contract events, and more. (disclosure: i work for quiknode)